# ASP webforms: How to use drop-down to show related data in textboxes asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I'm developing an application in asp.net webforms w an SQL server backend. I have a drop-down that contains "agency names". When I select the agency from the drop-down, it populates 7 other read-only textboxes with related data like address, phone number, etc. This currently works by using ADO recordset when the SelectedIndexChanged event fires for the drop-down, but it also posts the page back and reloads everything, which is not what I want.

[screenshot of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWPgg.png)

I know there are ajax controls in ASP webforms like updatepanel and triggers that are supposed to help me set up an asynchronous event to pull this data without reloading the page. How do I implement this? The drop-down is populated using an SQL datasource tag in the aspx HTML file.

Here is the current code in the code behind file:

```
Protected Sub cboRprtngAgncy_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboRprtngAgncy.SelectedIndexChanged
        If cboRprtngAgncy.SelectedValue <> "" Then
            'Fill in the agency details
            Dim Cnn As SqlConnection
            Dim Cmd As SqlCommand
            Dim Rdr As SqlDataReader
            Dim strRprtdPhn As String
            Dim strAltPhn As String


            'Set the objects and parameters up
            Cnn = New SqlConnection
           'Connection string deleted for security purposes.
            Cmd = New SqlCommand
            Cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure

            'Populate all the fields from the decedent table
            Cmd.CommandText = "spAgncyDtls_Slct"
            Cmd.Parameters.Add("@AgncyNmID", Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = IIf(Trim(cboRprtngAgncy.SelectedValue) = "", System.DBNull.Value, Trim(cboRprtngAgncy.SelectedValue))

            'Execute the objects and retrieve the decedent data
            Cnn.Open()
            Cmd.Connection = Cnn
            Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader

            Rdr.Read()

            strRprtdPhn = Rdr("AgncyPhnMn").ToString
            If strRprtdPhn <> "" Then strRprtdPhn = Left(strRprtdPhn, 3) + "-" + Mid(strRprtdPhn, 4, 3) + "-" + Right(strRprtdPhn, 4)

            strAltPhn = Rdr("AgncyPhnAlt").ToString
            If strAltPhn <> "" Then strAltPhn = Left(strAltPhn, 3) + "-" + Mid(strAltPhn, 4, 3) + "-" + Right(strAltPhn, 4)

            txtRprtdPhnNmbr.Text = strRprtdPhn
            txtRprtdAltPhn.Text = strAltPhn
            txtRprtngAddrss.Text = Rdr("AgncyStrt").ToString
            txtRprtngZp.Text = Rdr("AgncyZp").ToString
            txtRprtngCty.Text = Rdr("AgncyCty").ToString
            txtRprtngStt.Text = Rdr("AgncyStt").ToString
            txtAgncyNmbr.Text = Rdr("AgncyFx").ToString


            Rdr.Close()
            If Cnn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then Cnn.Close()

            Cnn.Dispose()
            Cmd.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
```

And here is the code in the aspx HTMLfile:

```html
<label>Reporting Agency</label><br />
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboRprtngAgncy" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldsAgncyNms" DataTextField="AgncyNm" DataValueField="AgncyNmID" Width="350px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="16px" Font-Bold="True" TabIndex="25" AutoPostBack="True" Enabled="true" /><br />
                                <label>Agency #</label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgncyNmbr" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" TabIndex="26" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#E8EDEE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#000000" ForeColor="#727372" CssClass="border-field" /><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-7">
                                <label>Reported By</label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRprtdBy" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" TabIndex="27" ReadOnly="False" BackColor="#ffffff" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#000000" ForeColor="#000000" /><br />
                                <label>Reported Phone</label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRprtdPhnNmbr" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" TabIndex="28" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#E8EDEE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#000000" ForeColor="#727372" /><br />
                                <label>Alternate Phone</label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRprtdAltPhn" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" TabIndex="29" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#E8EDEE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#000000" ForeColor="#727372" CssClass="border-field" /><br />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                        </div>
                        <br />

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-7">
                                <label>Reporting Address</label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRprtngAddrss" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" Width="500px" TabIndex="30" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#E8EDEE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#000000" ForeColor="#727372" /><br />
                                <label>City</label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRprtngCty" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" TabIndex="31" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#E8EDEE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#000000" ForeColor="#727372" /><br />
                                <label>State</label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRprtngStt" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" TabIndex="32" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#E8EDEE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#000000" ForeColor="#727372" /><br />
                                <label>Zip Code</label><br />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRprtngZp" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="12px" Font-Bold="True" Width="150px" TabIndex="33" ReadOnly="true" BackColor="#E8EDEE" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="#000000" ForeColor="#727372" />

                            </div>
```

I'm thinking I need to use javascript to set up an asynchronous event to grab the data and throw it into those 7 textboxes. I'm familiar but still new to Javascript, can anyone tell me how to set that up?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try setting the autopostback = false of the control?

Comment: I did that, and now nothing happens when I select something from the dropdown. It doesn't fire the ADO stuff in the code behind file. I think I need to use AJAX controls or write some kind of Javascript that will pull the data I need into those textboxes?

Comment: Postback cannot be avoided; you can only mask it with update panels (works well), but the postback still happens in the background. I'm sure there are examples on this site.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Webforms?  I ask because you mention cshtml files which are not used in Webforms.  Webforms use aspx files.

Comment: yes, I am using webforms... just been bouncing back and forth so much I got confused lol. Changing that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using three different methods to run asynchronous events: the UpdatePanel built in control for ASP webforms, a javascript event using an API, and a javascript event using an exposed method in the code behind file for the page. I will try to post examples for each of these methods some time in the near future.

Comment: I am a complete noob at asp.net and I am interested how you finally did it.